# Javascript returns pending state even thought there is a await (atlas mongoDB client)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, atlas

```js
class createuser {
    constructor(url){
        this.userid = this.getuserid()
        this.user = {name:url[2],userid:this.userid,notes:{}}
        this.passwordobj = {userid: this.userid,password: url[3]}
    }
    async getuserid(){
        const DBclient = new mongoclient(uri)
        try {
            const database = DBclient.db('NotesApp');
            const Users = database.collection('Users');
      
          // Query for a userdata that has the title 'Back to the Future'
            const userdata = await Users.findOne({},{sort:{userid: -1}}); 
            return userdata.userid+1
        } finally {
          // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
          await DBclient.close();
        }
    }
}

const newuser = new createuser(["","signup","kushi","password123"])
console.log(newuser);
```

this is my code and it returns this :

```
PS C:\Users\7A7z\Documents\node> node NotesApiv2
createuser {
  userid: Promise { <pending> },
  user: { name: 'kushi', userid: Promise { <pending> }, notes: {} },
  passwordobj: { userid: Promise { <pending> }, password: 'password123' }
}
```

it returns pending even though there is a await

i expected the userid to be one above the highest userid in the database

Comment: `async` functions/methods **always** return promises, so `this.userid = this.getuserid()` sets `this.userid` to the promise returned by `getuserid`. You can't wait for anything asynchronous to happen during a synchronous call like a constructor. If you want to perform asynchronous operations when creating those objects and not return the object until the async work is complete, your best bet is a static async builder method the caller can `await` instead of a constructor. (It's technically *possible* for a constructor to return a promise, but it's so unusual it's not a good idea.)

Comment: I will also add that this is not atomic, the only way to achieve atomic incremental userId using mongodb is to maintain another collection with a counter and use `findOneAndUpdate` on that counter.